# Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания?

Tags: пунктуация

Лиза два раза оставалась на второй год. Не с кем ей было рисовать крючочки в прописях, считать палочки и учить буквы. И главное, никто ей не помог понять, зачем надо учиться в школе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Все знаки препинания расставлены верно, нет замечаний**. Вводное слово "главное" не отделяется запятой от присоединительного союза И. Предложение №3 ― сложноподчиненное с придаточным изъяснительным, запятая ставится перед союзным словом.